# Is it feasible to modify a combo-amp so the line-out doesn't silence the speaker?

Tags: amplifiers

I'm considering this small bass amp, primarily for practising at home: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Vox-PATHFINDER-Combo-Bulldog-Speakers/dp/B002YC36ZI

A few people have said it's also capable for small venues, or on-stage, but it has the common practice feature that plugging in to the line-out silences the main speaker. This is unhelpful for using it on-stage, where you would perhaps like to use the amp for stage sound and feed the line-out into the mixing desk. Of course you *could* mic it but we tend not to do that for bass amps.

I'm sure this will vary from amp to amp but can someone give an informed opinion/educated guess whether these type of amps lend themselves to simple modifications, such as disabling the silent practice mode? Is it likely to be a very simple circuit (disconnect a wire) or some computer-controlled chip/circuit-board that makes this impracticable?

Comment: Not an answer, thus a comment. Do you have a guitar amp that could be used for practising, as modifying a new amp will invalidate its guarantee.

Comment: The amp could certainly be modified, but why not simply use a DI box to split the signal, running it into both the amp and the desk. That's the way they've done it at many venues I've played at.

Comment: @Johannes I've used DI boxes a fair amount but only ever as an 'adapter' between acoustic guitar and mixing desk. Is acting as a 'splitter' a standard feature or would I have to look specifically for a DI that does this?

Comment: @Mr.Boy, I think most DI boxes can do this, but look for one with both "thru" (to amp) and a balanced output (to desk).

Answer (score 2):

Many bass amps have a *DI output* (XLR jack), which, unlike a line out, is actually intended for routing into a live mixing console. For bass amps which don't have this, it's actually often best to use an external DI, *entirely before the amp*. You also lose preamp sound shaping then, but whether the Pathfinder actually does anything useful to the sound there... I'd have my doubts. – In fact, some live engineers prefer putting their own DI in front of even a high-quality bass amp, because this way they have better control of how the bass will sit in the mix.

For bass you don't need a top-notch DI, but a decent active one would be a good investment.

That said, this kind of plug-in-mute switch *is* indeed a very simple circuit that you can easily disable yourself<sup>†</sup>. It is usually implemented as an extra contact which doesn't contact the plug, but the T contact – but only if *no* cable is plugged in.

[image: Jack bypass switch]

To disable, simply make this contact permanent.

Be aware that using the line-out to go into a mixing console may not work well anyway. This output doesn't really have the right impedance for a mic input, and it's not balanced, so you'll probably get mains hum. This can be avoided with a DI, but... as I said, you'd probably best use a DI entirely before the amp, then the issue doesn't arise in the first place.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Voids warranty, of course.</sub>

Comment: Might also possibly lead to impedance issues, as the circuit would then be feeding 2 different outputs simultaneously.

Comment: @Tetsujin: theoretically, but the internal input to the power amp is probably so high-impedance that this doesn't matter.

Comment: ah, wasn't actually aware of what the impedances would be. Fair point :)

Comment: Thanks for the considered answer, and why it might not be ideal. I believe this amp does provide some level of FX/tone but imagine I wouldn't use it a great deal if at all. I'm fairly sure that since it's only a cheap amp it has no XLR-out.